# getting only the last value in for loop

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

my Vf page is

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!templook}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6"   >
    <apex:column headervalue="Payment For">
        {!payfor}
    </apex:column> 
    <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price">
        {!price}
    </apex:column>
</apex:datatable>
```

and in my constructor class

```
public class sitepage2 {
    public list<temp_invoice_lookup__c> templook{ get; set; }
    public sitepage2(){
        tempinvoiceid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('tempinvoiceid');
        templook = [select items_name__c,item_price__c,temp_invoice1__c from temp_invoice_lookup__c where Temp_Invoice1__c=:tempInvoiceid];
        for(integer i =0; i<templook.size();i++){
            payfor = templook[i].items_Name__c;
            price = templook[i].item_price__c;
        }
    }
    public void save(){
        for(integer i =0; i<templook.size();i++){
          itemlst.itemname = payfor;
          itemlst.Unitprice = price;
          system.debug('itemssss'+payfor +itemlst.itemname );
        } 
        itemslist.add(itemlst);
    }
}
```

getting only the last value in for loop....How should I overcome this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping through your data in VF but never actually displaying items from the SELECT!

You display the variables `payfor` and `price` (and earlier in Apex you've carefully overwritten their values in the loop so indeed they contain only last item's data).

Change the VF to

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!templook}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6"   >
    <apex:column headervalue="Payment For">{!item.items_Name__c}</apex:column> 
    <apex:column value="{!item.item_price__c}" /> <!-- even better -->
</apex:datatable>
```

Comment: if i use like that in my external site I can't able to see those values...But internally it is running dont know y?

Comment: Does your `templook` has a publicly available getter? either `public List<temp_invoice_lookup__c> templook {get;private set}` or maybe `public List<temp_invoice_lookup__c> getTemplook()`?

Comment: `public list<temp_invoice_lookup__c>  templook{ get; set; }`

Comment: Weird! Can you post a bit more of your controller (the snippet you've pasted doesn't look correct because it shows a SELECT and loop that just floats in the class body (next to a `save()` method. Is the `templook` data retrieved in constructor? In another method? In your original code is the `{!payfor}` displayed as many times as many rows there were returned from the query (make sure for example there are 2 or more, then run the page)

Comment: `public class sitepage2 {   public list<temp_invoice_lookup__c>  templook{ get; set; }public sitepage2(){tempinvoiceid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('tempinvoiceid');templook = [select items_name__c,item_price__c,temp_invoice1__c from temp_invoice_lookup__c where Temp_Invoice1__c=:tempInvoiceid];for(integer i =0; i<templook.size();i++){payfor = templook[i].items_Name__c;price = templook[i].item_price__c;}}}` and after this save method comes.I'm running the page when payfor is for 3

Comment: got the answer....Need to add object in my site forgot that.Thanks for ur help @eyescream

Comment: You're welcome :D I should have spotted the clue in controller name. Check if you can make VF code even cleaner: `<apex:column value="{!item.item_price__c}" />` (you'll get the field label for free, translated if you'll ever have to worry about it in future...). Make a new answer & accept it so the question goes off the radar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6472/discussion-between-eagerin-sf-and-eyescream)